# Access Firefox extension XPCOM object from Javascript inside an HTML page

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xpcom

I'm trying to get the most basic XPCOM javascript object to be accessible to the javascript I load into my webpage. I'm using the example code from this tutorial: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/How_to_Build_an_XPCOM_Component_in_Javascript

Here is my set up:

**install.rdf:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">

    <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
        <em:id>helloworld@thellamatesting.com</em:id>
        <em:name>Hello World</em:name>
        <em:version>1.0</em:version>
        <em:type>2</em:type>
        <em:creator>The Llama</em:creator>
        <em:description>Testing</em:description>

        <em:targetApplication>
            <Description>
                <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
                <em:minVersion>2.0</em:minVersion>
                <em:maxVersion>20.0</em:maxVersion>
            </Description>
        </em:targetApplication>
    </Description>      
</RDF>
```

**chrome.manifest**

```
content     helloworld    chrome/content/
content     helloworld    chrome/content/ contentaccessible=yes
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://helloworld/content/browser.xul

component {4762b5c0-5b32-11e2-bcfd-0800200c9a66} components/HelloWorld.js
contract @thellamatesting.com/helloworld;1 {4762b5c0-5b32-11e2-bcfd-0800200c9a66}

locale  helloworld  en-US   locale/en-US/
```

**components/HelloWorld.js**

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");

function HelloWorld() {
    // If you only need to access your component from Javascript, uncomment the following line:
    this.wrappedJSObject = this;
}

HelloWorld.prototype = {
    classDescription: "My Hello World Javascript XPCOM Component",
    classID:          Components.ID("{4762b5c0-5b32-11e2-bcfd-0800200c9a66}"),
    //Also tried
    //classID:          Components.ID("4762b5c0-5b32-11e2-bcfd-0800200c9a66"),
    contractID:       "@thellamatesting.com/helloworld;1",
    QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI(),
    // Also tried
    //QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Components.interfaces.nsIHelloWorld]),
    hello: function() { 
        return "Hello World!"; 
    }
};

var components = [HelloWorld];
if ("generateNSGetFactory" in XPCOMUtils)
  var NSGetFactory = XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetFactory(components);  // Firefox 4.0 and higher
else
  var NSGetModule = XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetModule(components);    // Firefox 3.x
```

**Testing HTML:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="application/javascript">

            function go() {
                try {
                    var coms = Components;
                    alert(Components.classes);
                    var myComponent = Components.classes['@thellamatesting.com/helloworld;1'].getService().wrappedJSObject;
                    alert(myComponent.hello());
                } catch (anError) {
                        dump("ERROR: " + anError);
                }
            };

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button onclick="javascript:go()">Click to go</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

After all this, I end up with "Components.classes is undefined". Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Try to put some of this code in the form of a JSFiddle.

Comment: Hi Jules, I'm not sure that would help. The Components.classes is undefined, so the problem isn't with my in HTML javascript, it's with my extension somehow. But, just to be sure, I tried it, same result.

Comment: I don't see how  JSFiddle would help since Components is a privileged Mozilla only object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to gain access to the `Components` object from a javascript context, you need to have extended capabilities, that is, run from a `chrome://` URL. There *used* to be a way for a regular web page (served from http://) to request extended capabilities (called `UniversalXPConnect`) but it has been removed out of security concerns.

I think you should tell us a little more about what it is you're trying to achieve. If you're trying to export data from your addon into a webpage, the AddonSDK (see https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/) has a very good protocol for doing that called page-mod; it allows you to inject data into web pages.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Thanks for the reply. My end goal is to create a plugin which will allow my web application to communicate with the clipboard. Since Firefox changed their security policies our software can no longer copy/paste, which is a big problem. Unfortunately, I can't direct people to a chrome:// URL. Do I have any other options?

Comment: I would suggest creating an Addon with the SDK; page-mod allows you to attach a script to a given web page:. What you could do is:
* attach a page-mod only on your webapp's domain;
* the content script would expose global functions on the window object, e.g. `window.foo = function () { ... }`.
* your webapp would call the foo function
* the role of the foo function is to use the `port` to communicate with the addon; the addon would then do job of using the clipboard.

Comment: See https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.12/modules/sdk/page-mod.html for more insights, hopefully things will make more sense once you read this.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! This worked really well. I still wasn't able to attach a function directly to the window, but using CustomEvents I was able to accomplish the same thing. I'll post my code below in case someone else may want it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jonathan's advice I was able to come up with a great solution to this problem. Here is the code I'm using:

main.js:

```
var data = require("self").data;
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
const {Cc,Ci} = require("chrome");

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptFile: data.url("copy-helper.js"),
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.on("handleCopy", function(copyInfo) {

            var gClipboardHelper = Cc["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboardhelper;1"].getService(Ci.nsIClipboardHelper);
            gClipboardHelper.copyString(copyInfo.dataToCopy);
        });
    }
});
```

copy-helper.js:

```
window.addEventListener("copyEvent", function (event) {

    self.port.emit('handleCopy', event.detail.copyInfo);

}, false);
```

*in my apps javascript*

```
var event = new CustomEvent("copyEvent", {
    detail:{
        copyInfo: {dataToCopy:"my string"}
    }
});
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Hope this helps anyone else who's ran into this issue!

Comment: That's a great solution, thanks for sharing it. If you were to submit your addon to AMO, I would suggest you use the builtin addon-module called "clipboard", since it provides a nice wrapper that doesn't rely on `require("chrome")` (see https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/clipboard.html) but since this is only for your internal website...